# ubuntu partition grub mount failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have tried install a Ubuntu 15.1 partition on my window's 10 lenovo t450 machine with a usb. After running boot-repair in Ubuntu, I found out there was a problem with mounting grub2's core.img with my system. I'm not too sure how to fix this. Or maybe there was something else that I did incorrectly while installing Ubuntu.

I have change the boot orders in bios and it still doesn't work.

[Boot-repair summary (Line 49 to 53)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14670312/)

This is the command output of fdisk -l:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296 395669503 395102208 188.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  395669504 395671551      2048     1M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  464762880 498069503  33306624  15.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda7  395671552 464762879  69091328    33G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Boot to Windows.
2. Download and install [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html).
3. Launch EasyUEFI.
4. In EasyUEFI, move the `ubuntu` option to the top of the list.
5. Reboot.

With any luck, GRUB will come up and give you the option of booting either Ubuntu or Windows.